# Dynamic host-name (using SNI) based routing with haproxy on TCP

Tags: tcp, routes, haproxy, sni

TCP router using haproxy.

**Use case:**
1) Request (TCP/SSL) comes to haproxy
2) haproxy reads the SNI (Server Name Indication) data from the request (subdomain.example.com), extract "subdomain" from the host name
3) Now, this request has to be passed on to a backend server (subdomain.local)

**Implementation**

```
frontend tcp_ssl_test
    bind 5432 ssl crt /etc/ssl/private/example.com.pem  
    mode tcp
    default_backend tcp_ssl_test_backend

backend tcp_ssl_test_backend
    mode tcp
    acl app_a req_ssl_sni -i subdomain1.andromeda.io
    acl app_b req_ssl_sni -i subdomain2.andromeda.io
    use-server bb1 if app_a
    use-server bb2 if app_b
    server bb1 subdomain1.local
    server bb2 subdomain2.local
```

**Problem**
If there are many more "subdomains", how can this be done dynamically?

**Can the "subdomain" part be extracted from sni host name and be passed on to the `server` keyword?**

For example, something like the below snippet would be great:

```
acl app_a req_ssl_sni -i (?<subdomain>.+)\.andromeda\.io
use-server bb1 if app_a
server bb1 $subdomain.local
```

Comment: What version of HAProxy?  Many things are possible in 1.6 that are impossible in previous versions... but servers cannot be dynamically instantiated.  You will have to declare a server to represent each actual back-end server.

Comment: `HA-Proxy version 1.6.3`. We were looking at creating servers dynamically. But, since that is not possible, can we have a dynamic `use-server` line? Or any other dynamic alternatives to achieve this?